# Why would setting 'httpOnlyCookies="true"' disrupt sessions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, session-state, httponly

In my asp.net mvc web.config file I've set the following...

```
<httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

Everything works fine on my dev machine and the live server but on the staging server the sessions simply don't work. There's some code that relies on there being a value in session and it always responds that it can't find it.

How could a server configuration be effected in this way by the attribute?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: This attribute shouldn't disrupt sessions. Sessions are tracked by HttpOnly cookies anyway. I am afraid your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: OK... I suppose it must have been a coincidence that things started working when I set it to false! I'll give it another go...

Comment: What browser are you using? Some don't accept httpOnly cookies, like Safari.

Comment: IE, Chrome etc. That's not the issue though because things work fine on the live server.

Comment: Gosh this is confusing. I've narrowed it down... IE (8) doesn't persist the asp.net authentication ticket when its set on the staging server. The other browsers don't have a problem with it and nor does IE (8) have a problem on the live or dev sites!